# Invariants of parabolic subgroups

Tags: finite-groups, invariant-theory, reflection

Let $G$ be a finite reflection group acting on $R^n$. Then for each point $x\in R^n$ we can look at its stabilizer $G_x$. Since $G$ is a finite reflection group, its ring of invariants is a polynomial ring in $n$ algebraically independent polynomials, i.e. $R[X]^G=R[p_1,\ldots, p_n]$. Now suppose I have these generators, is there a way to get the generators of the invariant ring of the groups $G_x$, which are also finite reflection groups?